# STX: How to process elements that have a more higher level than a matched element has?

Tags: xml, stx

...or maybe somehow get child's content?

Hi guys, I'm using STX because I've got huge XML files.

I have some input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ME>
  <DataContainer id="1">
    <attributes>
      <DataType>vsDataF</DataType>
      <vsDataF>
        <label>lable-F</label>
        <zzz>100</zzz>
      </vsDataF>
    </attributes>
    <DataContainer id="1">
      <attributes>
        <DataType>vsData1</DataType>
        <vsData1>
          <label>lable-1</label>
          <zzz>1000</zzz>
        </vsData1>
      </attributes>
    </DataContainer>
    <DataContainer id="1">
      <attributes>
        <DataType>vsData2</DataType>
        <vsData2>
          <label>lable-2</label>
          <zzz>2000</zzz>
        </vsData2>
      </attributes>
    </DataContainer>
  </DataContainer>
  <DataContainer id="2">
    <attributes>
      <DataType>vsDataG</DataType>
      <vsDataG>
        <label>lable-G</label>
        <zzz>200</zzz>
      </vsDataG>
    </attributes>
</ME>
```

and I need to get such output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<main>
  <vsDataF>
    <id>1</id>
    <label>lable-F</label>
    <zzz>100</zzz>
    <vsData1>
      <id>1</id>
      <label>lable-1</label>
      <zzz>1000</zzz>
    </vsData1>
    <vsData2>
      <id>1</id>
      <label>lable-2</label>
      <zzz>2000</zzz>
    </vsData2>
  </vsDataF>
  <vsDataG>
    <id>2</id>
    <label>lable-G</label>
    <zzz>200</zzz>
  </vsDataG>
</main>
```

I wrote a transform that does it partly

```
<stx:transform
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:stx="http://stx.sourceforge.net/2002/ns"
  output-method="xml">

  <stx:variable name="table_name"/>

  <stx:template match="/">
    <main>
      <stx:process-children/>
    </main>
  </stx:template>

  <!-- DataContainters -->
  <stx:template match="ME/DataContainer/attributes/DataType">
    <stx:assign name="table_name" select="."/>
    <stx:element name="{$table_name}">
      <id>
        <stx:value-of select="../../@id"/>
      </id>
    </stx:element>
  </stx:template>

</stx:transform>
```

I know, there are few stx:process, for example stx:process-children, stx:process-self, stx:process-siblings, but this case it's does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this problem. I learned how `stx:group` and `stx:buffer` work, it was difficult for me, but I managed to do it.

```
<stx:transform
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:stx="http://stx.sourceforge.net/2002/ns"
  output-method="xml">

  <stx:variable name="table_name"/>
  <stx:buffer name="columns"/>

  <stx:template match="/">
    <main>
      <stx:process-children/>
    </main>
  </stx:template>

  <stx:group name="copy-all" pass-through="all"/>

  <!-- Columns -->
  <stx:template match="DataContainer/attributes/*[2]/*">
    <stx:element name="{local-name()}">
      <stx:value-of select="."/>
    </stx:element>
  </stx:template>

  <!-- DataType --> 
  <stx:template match="DataContainer/attributes/*[2]">
    <stx:assign name="table_name" select="local-name()"/>
    <stx:result-buffer name="columns" clear="yes">
      <stx:process-children/>
    </stx:result-buffer>
  </stx:template>

  <!-- DataContainer -->
  <stx:template match="DataContainer/*[1]" priority="2">
    <stx:process-self/>
    <stx:element name="{$table_name}">
      <id>
        <stx:value-of select="../@id"/>
      </id>
      <stx:process-buffer name="columns" group="copy-all"/>
      <stx:process-siblings/>
    </stx:element>
  </stx:template>

</stx:transform>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution mate!